# sleep in thread with while loop without sleep in UIThread

Tags: android, multithreading, while-loop, ui-thread

How can I make use of a delay in the while loop without also delaying the UIThread?
My while loop should update the UI everytime the app run through the loop but there should also be the possibility to interact with a button. The problem I have with my current version is that the app pauses when the while loop is started until the while loop is finished and then updates the UI. I want it to update the UI with every pass through.

Do you have any ideas, maybe also an alternative way that is more efficient?

This is my current version:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class ReaderFragment extends Fragment
{

ProgressBar progress_in_main_thread;
private int progressBarStatus = 0;
TextView main_text;
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(" ");
String[] splitted_text;
Button start_button;
Button pause_button;
public boolean paused;
int index = 0;
long wait = 1000;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
//Layout des Fragments verknuepfen
{
    View ReaderFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reader_fgmt, container, false);

    progress_in_main_thread = (ProgressBar) ReaderFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.reader_progress);
    progress_in_main_thread.setProgress(0);
    progress_in_main_thread.setVisibility(progress_in_main_thread.VISIBLE);

    main_text = (TextView) ReaderFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.center_view);

    start_button = (Button) ReaderFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.go);
    start_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view)
       {
           if(InputFragment.text.trim().length() == 0)
           {
               Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Es wurde kein Text eingegeben!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
           else
           {
               paused = false;
               splitted_text = p.split(InputFragment.text);
               progress_in_main_thread.setMax(splitted_text.length-1);

               mainThread();
           }

       }
    });

    pause_button = (Button) ReaderFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.pause);
    pause_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
                paused = true;
        }
    });




    return ReaderFragmentView;
}

private void mainThread()
{
    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            while(progressBarStatus < (splitted_text.length)-1)
            {
                progressBarStatus = index;

                progress_in_main_thread.setProgress(progressBarStatus);
            }
        }
    }).start();

    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {

        while(!paused)
        {
           main_text.setText(splitted_text[index]);

           if(paused)
           {
                break;
           }
           else if(index == (splitted_text.length)-1)
           {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Ende", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
           }
            index++;
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(wait);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        }

    });
}
}
```

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

By definition, you cannot delay the UI thread without delaying the UI thread.

Fundamentally, you need to switch from a *loop* style of program to an *event* driven one, which in which the Android UI must be handled.  Your program will not have a while loop - instead, the Android framework will call into your code to execute event functions, each of which must return as quickly as possible.

Android already does this out of the box to deliver user interaction events such as touches and button pushes, and lifecycle events.  To add events for periodic evolution of your UI (what you were trying to do with the while loop and delay), you can create a Timer and have its TimerTask push some UI related work to do onto the UI Thread using RunOnUiThread; if what you need to do does not involve the UI, then you can just do it in the background thread where the TimerTask executes.

In your posted code, it looks like you might have attempted to create your own background thread which would run a loop with a sleep delay, and push work to the UI thread with RunOnUiThread; technically that is workable, but not really encouraged compared to the timer method.  However, there are two problems with the way that you did it:

- First, you named the launcher method for your background thread mainThread, which is a bit confusing as on Android the "main thread" and the "UI thread" are one and the same - it would be better to call it createBackgroundThread() or something.
- Second, you have the while and sleep occurring within the code which it pushes to the UI thread for execution, which is unworkable.  You will need to move the while loop and sleep out into the background thread and instead have it repeatedly use RunOnUiThread when you need to push onto the UI Thread small batches of work which can immediately complete, such as each actual visual update.

Also you may want to put some thought into if your implementation could end up creating multiple concurrent background threads as a result of repeated button pushes, or one of your threads it is still running when a significant Activity Lifecycle event occurs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Anyway, could you give me an example to your Second point? I think I didn't really know how to do that.

Comment: Just move the RunOnUiThread inside so it wraps only the ui update work, and none of the looping or sleeping.

Comment: ok, and than execute it withe the TimerTask? Got it, thank you

Comment: No, the timer task approach would be instead of your thread, sleep, and while - you'd convert the sleep duration to the timer interval.